# Difficulty in understanding a http and https packet

Tags: http, networking, tcp

What is contained in a HTTP packet? For example, a FTP data download request will have "RETR" content in it, a FTP data upload will have a "STOR" content in it and a FTP completed request will have a "226 file" file content in it. In a similar way, what will a HTTP and HTTPs request packet will have? What will its completed request have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), which defines the HTTP protocol.